# How can I use the iOS Simulator to simulate an out of disk space condition?

Tags: ios, iphone

What is a practical way to test an "out of disk space" condition using the iOS Simulator?

Comment: You could take the relevant directory below `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`; and mount a limited-size partition at the device image e.g. make a disk image, copy the content of the original device into the disk image and then try that. This isn't an answer because it's a lot of effort and doesn't correspond to the real situation on a device

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Create a small disk image:

```
hdiutil create -size 2m -fs HFS+ /tmp/2meg.dmg
```

Mount it to the relevant directory in your simulator app, e.g.:

```
hdiutil attach /tmp/2meg.dmg -mountpoint /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../data/Applications/.../Library/Caches
```

Run app and perform your tests. This can also be done while the app is running. In this case you probably don't want to mount it as `Caches` or `Documents` directory directly because this would hide current files in those folders. Mount to a sub-directory instead. If this is not easily possible without changing paths in your app, mount the image somewhere else and copy data over before mounting it on top of the nonempty directory.

To unmount:

```
hdiutil detach /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devi...
```

However, please note that the detach operation fails if the mount point is moved. This happens all the time because Apple renames simulator directories on iOS 8 every time an app is run. In this case use the `mount` command to find the device you have mounted, e.g. `/dev/disk3s1 /Users/.../Library/...`, then unmount the disk image using the device name instead of the mount point:

```
hdiutil detach disk3s1
```

Comment: This worked. Also, Note that the `mkfile` utility (on Mac OS X) was helpful for me in stuffing the empty space with a custom size file.

Comment: Great answer. Also, at least in Xcode 9, running the app again in the same simulator doesn't change the directory name, so you can use the same mount for multiple runs.

Comment: Does this actually trigger iOS to run its logic when disk space is low? That is, send warnings to the app, remove files from the cache directory, etc.

Comment: Not sure if I miss something. How does mounting a disk image help simulating low disk space situation?

Comment: This did not work for me. I must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

This isn't practical on the simulator (you'd have to fill up your Mac's disk.) The best way to achieve this test case is to use an actual device and fill with Music via iTunes and test on device.

Comment: Are you aware of a quick way to do this?  I have a brand new iPad that we got as a testing device and need to fill 25GB fairly quickly.

Comment: Quick way to fill with music you mean? I'd actually maybe try videos too.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, just turned on the camera and let it run for a couple of hours.

Comment: I wrote an app that fills the storage pretty quickly, for anyone who's in need :) https://github.com/AppWerkstatt/NoMoreStorage

Comment: @LucèBrùlè Thanks for the app did the trick pretty quick it wrote at around 30 Mb/s

Comment: Sync some big video files using itunes to your device. @akousmata