# storage greater than system

Tags: ios, objective-c, storage

I want to simulate a shortage of storage, so I try to copy files util the storage is full, but I found it will never get to that, and I found the occuped storage is greater than system, how can this happen?
the code is as follows:

```
+ (void)copeFiles
{
    NSString *srcPath = [self cloudStorageCacheFolderPath];
    NSLog(@"copy: src path:%@ ,size:%f", srcPath, [self sizeOfcloudStorageCacheFolder]);
    int base = 300;
    int i = base;
    while (1) {
        i++;
        if (i > base + 100) {
            break;
        }
        NSInteger freeSizeM = [self freeFileStorageSize];
        if (freeSizeM > 1024) {
            NSString *newFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d", srcPath, i];
            [self copyFolderContentFromSrc:srcPath toDestPath:newFilePath];
            NSLog(@"copy: i:%d, freeSizeM:%li", i, (long)freeSizeM);
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
+ (void)copyFolderContentFromSrc:(NSString *)srcPath toDestPath:(NSString *)dstPath
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSLog(@"copy: src:%@ dst:%@", srcPath, dstPath);
    BOOL isDir;
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dstPath isDirectory:&isDir] || !isDir) {
        BOOL sucess = [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dstPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        NSLog(@"copy: isDir:%d sucess:%d", isDir, sucess);
    }
    NSArray* array = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:srcPath error:nil];
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *fileName in array) {
        i++;
        NSString *srcFullPath = [srcPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSString *toFullPath = [dstPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSError *error;
        BOOL isSucess = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:srcFullPath toPath:toFullPath error:&error];
        NSLog(@"copy:%d", i);
        if (!isSucess) {
            NSLog(@"copy:error:%@", error);
        }
    }
}
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97aCU.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l4O2.png)
The images may be invisible, so I describe the phenomenon simply in advance.My iphone is 32GB in total, but the available storage is 93GB showed in setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It will also increase if you run it again :)

The reason behind it is that It will store the reference only not an actual file. and I have done the same in my mac system to fill the space for simulator and I have ended up with same 256GB system showing 4.3 TB of space

- In Device, you can fill space using record a video and still you can not get that error because Apple will manage it like this way.

1) Delete all temporary files that were stored in All App directory.

2) And then Clear cache memory.

Apple will manage the storage space management very well and there is still some mystery about it.

Comment: thanks. Then, it will be hard to judge whether there is more storage to use. Do you have any idea?

Comment: yes, I have found one way you have to do it by creating a partition on your Mac system and point that partition to the simulator 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931711/how-can-i-use-the-ios-simulator-to-simulate-an-out-of-disk-space-condition

Check this it may help :)